# How to display fixed size DIVs within another DIV inline?

Tags: html, css

My page shows fixed size DIVs within another/parent DIV inline. And it works fine. It moves extra DIVs to another line. See picture below:
[image]

The problem appears when the DIV content becomes more that one line. DIV size is still fixed but it moves other DIVs down inline. See picture below:
[image]

So how to show all DIVs with fixed size and position regardless it's content. (Assume the content lines number won't exceed DIV height). Here is my page:

```
<html><head>

<style>
.parentDiv{
    background-color:   #eeeeee;
}

.childDiv{
    display:            inline-block;
    background-color:   #66ff99;
    width:              200px;
    height:             100px;
    padding:            20px;
    margin:             5px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="childDiv">
        test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 
    </div>

    <div class="childDiv">
        test 1
    </div>

    <div class="childDiv">
        test 1
    </div>

    <div class="childDiv">
        test 1
    </div>
    <div class="childDiv">
        test 1
    </div>
    <div class="childDiv">
        test 1
    </div>
    <div class="childDiv">
        test 1
    </div>
    <div class="childDiv">
        test 1
    </div>
    <div class="childDiv">
        test 1
    </div>                    
    <div class="childDiv">
        test 1
    </div>    

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `vertical-align:top` in `.childDiv` because `inline-block` is  by default `vertical-align:baseline`

```css
.parentDiv {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.childDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #6f9;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="childDiv">
    test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1
  </div>

  <div class="childDiv">
    test 1
  </div>

  <div class="childDiv">
    test 1
  </div>

  <div class="childDiv">
    test 1
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv">
    test 1
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv">
    test 1
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv">
    test 1
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv">
    test 1
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv">
    test 1
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv">
    test 1
  </div>
</div>
```